# Use classes other than QWidget with QGridLayout using PySide or PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pyside

I'm trying to arrange QPixmap and QLineEditor objects using QGridLayout, but I get the following error.

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QPixmap, int, int, int, int)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget, int, int, PySide.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = 0)
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget, int, int, int, int, PySide.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = 0)
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget)
```

All I could think of was to somehow make them QWidgets, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had to make the `QPixmap` an argument of a `QWidget`, such as `QLabel`. So I ended up doing:

```
imageBox = QtGui.QLabel(self)
imageBox.setGeometry(0,0,300,200)
imageBox.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd() + '/tmp.png').scaled(300,200))
```

and then adding that to the grid.